# Terraform always updating iam_policy_document's condition block

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I have a iam_policy_document resource with a condition block. In terraform condition blocks have a required argument named values. This is a set of possible values for the condition. However, in my case, the variable is a boolean. So the set is just one value, ["false"].

When I run terraform apply and then later run either terraform plan or terraform apply, terraform always says it will update this value from "false" to ["false"]. Is there a way to get it to stop updating this policy when nothing has actually changed?

Reference: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/iam_policy_document#values

I am using v0.15.1 on AWS.

Here is output of terraform plan when no terraform code has changed and no manual manipulation of the policy on AWS has happened. Notice it is updating the policy.

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.s3_test_bucket.aws_s3_bucket.main will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_s3_bucket" "main" {
        id                          = "test-for-stackoverflow"
      ~ policy                      = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              ~ Statement = [
                  ~ {
                      ~ Condition = {
                          ~ Bool = {
                              ~ aws:SecureTransport = "false" -> [
                                  + "false",
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                        [...]
```

Comment: What is your actual TF code that results in your problem?

Comment: It's hard to be specific without fuller details, but on the surface this looks like a situation where the S3 API has normalized the policy JSON in a way that the AWS provider didn't expect, and so the provider thinks it needs to "fix" the normalization. Since you are using `aws_iam_policy_document` to generate this policy you won't be able to directly influence what JSON it produces, and so I think the only workaround for you right now, if upgrading to the latest AWS provider doesn't help, would be to write the JSON policy contents directly yourself using the `jsonencode` function.

Comment: You can then structure it exactly the way the S3 API is normalizing it and avoid this failure to converge. For a real fix I think you'd need to open an issue with the AWS provider to see if it's possible to teach it about this normalization rule so that it won't try to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

you type aws:SecureTransport = array of 1, AWS update it to be a string so you have diff between deployed configuration and  terrafrom configuration file.
change the value to string
aws:SecureTransport = ["false"]
to
aws:SecureTransport = "false"

And it should solve it.